# i capture image from camera it work fine but when i open again my app image not save

Tags: android, image-capture, save-image

I have an app in which I try to capture user images from camera and also from gallery. The image capture works fine and the image is visible in the `ImageView` but when I restart the app the image disappears as if it wasn't saved.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;
    int REQUEST_CAMERA =1;
    int SELECT_FILE = 0;
    public String photoFileName;
    File photoFile = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);


        final FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                selectImage();


            }
        });
    }

    public void selectImage(){
        final CharSequence [] items = {"Camera","Gallery","Cancel"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Image");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("IntentReset")
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                if (items[i].equals("Camera")) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CAMERA);

                    try {
                       photoFile = createImageFile();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "Photo file can't be created, please try again",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
                                "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                                photoFile);
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);

                    }


                }else if (items[i].equals("Gallery")){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent,"Select File"),SELECT_FILE);
                 galleryAddPic();

                }else if (items[i].equals("Cancel")){
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }

            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

            Bundle bundle = null;
            if (data != null) {
                bundle = data.getExtras();
            }
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            if (bundle != null) {
                bitmap = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
            }
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE){
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(uri);
        }
    }

    private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(String.valueOf(photoFile));
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        photoFileName = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }


}
```

Comment: thanku Mike for guiding me for question query

Comment: restart apps means you repeat, so it will as fresh from the oven again

Answer (score 0):

While restart the app image is not showing becuase of all variable initialize again, for showing that you have to store it path locally.

Comment: i stored image using shared preference its working.